# Is there a quadrilateral where its diagonal equal to its pair of sides without being a parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

I can only think of such quadrilateral with combining two isoceles triangles but then it will become a parallelogram? Can anyone think of the quadrilateral in my question?

[image]

EDIT: Added a picture for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Move the bottom left vertex, keeping it the same distance from the bottom right vertex.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: But wouldn't I always get a quadrilateral formed by two isoceles triangles? Wouldn't it make the quadrilateral then a parallelogram?

Comment: Not if the isosceles triangles have different angles.

Comment: Thank you so much for creating the gif. It's more clear now.